# To Be In Treatment

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, prepositional-phrases

A question about "in treatment" [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/10/24/health/24bell.html?_r=0):

> Dr. Levis concurred. Though the disease is curable, and not transmissible when a victim is ***in treatment***, the special stigma of the word leper remains.

Dictionaries don't have the phrase "*in treatment*".  Could it be specialized medical lingo?

Comment: The use of "in treatment" is based on the process like nature of most medical treatments especially that of leprosy as this passage indicates. It is not specialized medical lingo nor is it a specialized use of the word treatment. It is just a re-focusing of the word to allow more information to be given out. The specifics of it indicate the process-like nature of the treatment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I'd call it specialised, though I agree it seems to be being used in a way I haven't seen very often.

If you view 'treatment' as an ongoing process, rather than a single point or procedure, then one can be said to be 'in' it, much like saying 'in a job' or 'in a race'. A better way to phrase it would probably be 'when a victim is undergoing treatment'.

Answer (score 0):

Considering *in treatment* as *under treatment* shall work here. It is used as it would be in any normal case.

> When you are *in* meeting, behave properly

Certainly, here the advice is for someone who is *in* meeting. While the meeting is going on, his misbehavior is not accepted.